# select an input in Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I am very new to shiny apps.

Let's say I have a list `ll` {"first" -> "one","second" -> "two"}

```
selectInput('some_var',h4("some content"),
                              choices=ll)
```

In my input, I want to get as a default value "second", so that I have to get the index from the list. So I tried

```
test <- which(sapply(ll, FUN=function(X) "two" %in% X))
```

and then

```
selectInput('some_var',h4("some content"),
                                  choices=ll,selected=names(test))
```

But I stil get the default value in the `SelectInput`so "first". How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

hi I found the following simple answer

```
selectInput('some_var',h4("some content"),
                                  choices=ll,ll[2])
```